# Assigning array causes syntax error with certain data

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, arrays

I am making a script that uses the youtube api to search through videos and store details about some of them in a database.
I use javascript to get the data and then store it in a mysql database by using php.

It works fine most of the time but some characters seem to cause syntax error when I assign the data to a javascript array at this line:

```
var videoList = <?=$videoList; ?>;
```

It is specifically when I assign it and not when I use it, I have tried resetting the array right after it is assigned and it still causes the error.

One of the strings I found that appears to have caused the error is this one: (I know this line caused the problem before because it started working when I manually deleted it)

```
Hoppas ni mÃ¥r jÃ¤tte bra idag â¤ï¸undrar om ni vill att jag ska gÃ¶ra en annan video sÃ¥ fÃ¥r ni jÃ¤tte JÃ¤rna kommentera deâ
```

I use "utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci" in the database and charset="UTF-8" on my website. I am not sure if it is because of charset or some character it can't handle, maybe I need to convert the characters with some function.

Any idea how I can fix it?

#### Update:

I did like Dan Miller suggested and it didn't work at all.

I also tried what Adrianopolis suggested. I changed the collation of the table and column and already had the charset set in the header. It still cause the problem after changing collation.

Comment: Wrap it with quotes `var videoList = "<?=$videoList; ?>";`

Comment: NO, don't wrap it in quotes. Use a proper encoder to build proper JS literals `var videoList = <?=json_encode($videoList); ?>;`

Comment: I use json_encode in php: `return json_encode($return_arr);`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using MB4?
Change your cols from utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci to `utf8mb4_general_ci` and of course be sure you have `<meta charset="utf-8">` meta tag in your header. That worked for me for all cases.